# Accessing comment context menu in Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, adobe-acrobat, context-menu, adobe-reader

I have received a bunch of comments on a PDF document and I would like to efficiently navigate through them in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

I have activated the single-key accelerators which are helpful, but I would really like to set the status of the comment in the context menu without touching the mouse. Any ideas how to access this using the keyboard only?

[image: A bunch of triangles making a hexagon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how to access this using the keyboard only?

1. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to put the focus on the next comment, then
2. press the <kbd>context menu</kbd> key to open the context menu containing *Se̲t Status*, then
3. press <kbd>e</kbd> to open *Se̲t Status*.

[image: Acrobat Reader context menu]

#### Context menu key

The <kbd>context menu</kbd> key is this one:

[image: context menu key]

<sub>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key</sub>

#### Keys for working with comments

[image: Adobe Acrobat keyboard shortcuts for working with comments]

<sub>Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html#keys_for_working_with_comments</sub>

Comment: Not all keyboards have context menu key. `Shift + F10` can be used instead

Comment: I now know about the context menu key. But this hasn't solved my issue - if I have the comment selected and press the 'context menu' button it brings up the general context menu in Acrobat Reader. If I right-click in the comment then I get the correct context menu, but kind of defeats the purpose of not using the mouse

Comment: @driftingtides: The focus needs to be on the text with the comment, not inside the comment itself. I've added a screenshot to illustrate it. For me, the context menu shows up at the left upper corner, which is weird, but it works.

Comment: Now I see what you did there. I had hoped to see the comment box at the same time as I set its status, but that doesn't seem like an option in Adobe Reader.